# why is tables in lua designed in this way?

Tags: lua, lua-table

I am confused about below grammer in language lua:

```
w = {x=0, y=0}
w[1] = "another"
```

in my opinion, the first sentence descirbe the w as a dict-like strcture and next a array, are the w of the first and of the second same? if so, why? why can two different things can be stored in a w?

I'm a rookie in lua and also in english, pardon.

I want to know some thoughts of designation of lua and the explanation of my qustion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An array is conceptually just a series of key/value pairs. It's just that the "keys" are all integers and are a sequence of integers starting from (in Lua's case) 1.

Lua recognizes that a "dictionary" and "array" are really the same thing. It bundles these two concepts together into a single type: Lua's "table".

In a Lua table, keys can be (almost) anything. Including integers. Including integers starting from 1 and increasing. As such, a Lua table is said to have an "array portion", which are all of the integer keys from the integer 1 to the highest integer whose value is not `nil`. This is what it means to take the "length" of a table.

Comment: yes, i understand what you said. but two phenomena confused me.
the first:
in lua, we can use w.key to assign and get the value,  as you said that the number 1 is the key of "another", so I can call print(w.x) to get 0, but when I called print(w.1), I got an error. Obviously, the sentence of print(w.1) is a mistake in grammer of any other languages.

the second:
The usage of w["x"] and w[1] can pass complilation. Now that the x and 1 are the keys, why the symbol "" appears in first and not in second. 

are these phenomena just for grammatical reason?

incoherent expression, pardon.

Comment: @wangxiang: "*we can use w.key to assign and get the value*" No, you can use `w.key_that_happens_to_be_a_string_and_a_lua_identifier` to do that. "*Now that the x and 1 are the keys*" No, the keys are the integer `1` and the string `"x"`. Maybe you should read [the Lua reference manual](http://www.lua.org/docs.html), which explains all of this in detail.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just read the Lua 5.4 Reference Manual and got the answer at [ Table Constructors](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.4.9).  What a wonderful programming language.